# Call function every time table reloads

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to download the data from a public database. The webpage has a table, and whenever you click on a button "next", all of the rows are updated with new values. I want to download the table every time the button is pressed and new rows are added. Every time the button is pressed, it calls a function "foo()", so I'm essentially calling the function without needing to press the button.

This is what I'm currently executing in the console:

```
async function run(){
    // download 4 tables
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        // download current table
        download_table("table" + i + ".csv");
        // fetch next table
        await foo(i+1);
    }   
}
run();
```

What ends up happening is that I download the same table 4 times in a row, and then the table switches to the 4th page.

EDIT: Question is not the same as duplicate, as it is not affected by the values of the variable "i". Identical results occur even without the for loop, by hard-coding the values of i:1,2,3,4...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: looks like the download function may be async too...

Comment: I think it is async. How would I wait for it to finish in that case?

Comment: await download_table()